# Does nonexpanding map between manifolds decrease volume?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometries

(This question is a special case of a [question I asked at SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906080/nonexpanding-map-between-manifolds-decreases-volume), which got no answer there)

Let $M,N$ be **diffeomorphic** connected compact Riemannian manifolds, and let $f:M \to N$ be a surjective nonexpanding map (i.e Lipschitz with constant $1$).

Assume that $f$ is **strictly nonexpanding**, i.e there exists $p,q \in M$ such that $$d(f(p),f(q)) < d(p,q)$$

Is it true that $\operatorname{Vol}(N)<\operatorname{Vol}(M)$?

*Edit:*

I want $M,N$ to be **smooth** manifolds with or without boundary. 
[Nik's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/249476/46290) gives a counter example (when $\operatorname{Vol}(N)=\operatorname{Vol}(M)$), but I am not sure it is smooth in the sense mentioned above. (The same problem comes up in [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1914895/104576) given at S.E).

---

Note that if we do not assume $M,N$ are diffeomorphic then the answer is **negative**:

A counter-example is $f:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{S}^1, f(t)=e^{it}$.

**Partial result:**

In the case the manifolds are **one**-dimensional the answer is **positive**:

Assume otherwise. Then $\operatorname{Vol}(N)=\operatorname{Vol}(M)$. Since every two compact connected one-dimensional Riemannian manifolds with equal volumes are isometric, there exists an isometry $\phi:N \to M$.
Thus, $f \circ \phi:N \to N$ is surjective and nonexpanding, hence an isometry.

Comment: Do you continue to not assume $f$ is smooth?

Comment: Yes, I do not assume the map is smooth.

Comment: @Neal: Actually, even though I am not assuming smoothness, $f$ is in fact differentiable almost everywhere (via Rademacher's theorem). It is  not hard to show that at each point of differentiability $p \in M$, the singular values of the differential $df_p:T_pM \to T_{f(p)}N$ are not greater than one.

Comment: I think the answer is "yes" in the case that $f$ is actually a diffeomorphism. Compare the metric $g$ on $M$ to the pullback $h$ by $f$ of the metric on $N$. By the hypothesis that $f$ is nonexpanding, the pointwise eigenvalues of $h$ with respect to $g$ are all no greater than $1$. The hypothesis on distance implies the $h$-geodesic $\gamma$ connecting $p,q$ has shorter $h$-length than $g$-length, so by looking at the arc-length integral we should see at least one pointwise eigenvalue of $h$ wrt $g$ is strictly less than $1$. The volume inequality should follow by comparing volume forms.

Comment: (This is less general than what you are asking, however.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, if "compact manifold" means "compact manifold with boundary" (as it seems to from your example) and "diffeomorphic" means "with diffeomorphic interiors". My previous example wasn't right, as Willie Wong pointed out, because after gluing the result wasn't Riemannian. But we can fix that problem by a simple modification: let $M$ be the unit disk minus the region $y > \sqrt{|x|}$, and let $f$ be the map that zips up the slit. That works, doesn't it?

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you fold and glue the edges, don't you get an angle defect at $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$? Are you implicitly smoothing it a bit?

Comment: @WillieWong: yes, you're right.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thanks. I think your example works, however I am not entirely sure the map I am imagining is nonexpanding (weakly) at *every* two points. (The strict non expanding nature for *some* points is clear).

Comment: Actually, on second thought, doesn''t your map increase distances between points that are close to the boundary of $M$? (We measure the distances intrinsically, not by the Euclidean distance function which is extrinsic)

Comment: @AsafShachar: I thought you only asked for $d(f(p),f(q)) < d(p,q)$ for *some* $p,q$. My map doesn't increase any distances because every geodesic in $M$ is still a geodesic in $N$.

Comment: @NikWeaver Indeed, I have asked for strict decrease in the distance only for some points. However, I am not sure I have completely understood your construction. Could you please elaborate more on what  is $N$? Is it the whole unit disk, or "almost" all of it? or just the unit disk with a smaller region removed from it (compared to the region we remove in $M$)?

Comment: $N$ is what you get when you attach the points $(x,\sqrt{x})$ and $(-x, \sqrt{x})$ in $M$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Are you sure your $M,N$ are manifolds with boundary? (I think perhaps they are manifolds with corners, but I am not sure even that is true). Perhaps there is some singularity at the origin or (in $N$) in the "curve" you identify?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean. Topological manifolds with boundary are the same as topological manifolds with corners.

Comment: @NikWeaver I have a minor question regarding your map $f:M \to N$. If I am not wrong, than $f$ is a smooth isometric immersion between two manifolds with boundary, which maps some points on $\partial M$ to points in the interior. That is, I think the points of the form $(x,\sqrt x), x > 0$ (which lie $\partial M$), are mapped to points in the inteior of $N$, under the identification.

Comment: Hi @Nich, I have a question with the same spirit [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442092/if-x-x-have-the-same-varepsilon-packing-numbers-and-fx-to-x-surjectiv). Please have a look at it if you don't mind.